# Critique of composition design pattern requiring derived class

Tags: design-patterns, interfaces, inheritance

I have the following two inheritance chains:

```
 BaseQueryBuilder          BaseApplication
       |                          |
       |                          |
  AppQueryBuilder            Application
```

`BaseQueryBuilder` is an abstract class, which `AppQueryBuilder` extends by adding additional query builder methods that are specific to the application. `BaseApplication` is interface that `Application` implements. I'm using composition to merge the to, so the constructor for `Application` looks something like the following:

```
class Application(AppQueryBuilder queryBuilder) {
    _queryBuilder = queryBuilder;
}
```

Note that other functions in `Application` depend on the existence of methods in `AppQueryBuilder` that are *not* defined in `BaseQueryBuilder`, but rather added in the definition of `AppQueryBuilder`.

**Question**: Is this poor style? I'm a bit uneasy about the fact that `Application`'s constructor requires a concrete implementation, named `AppQueryBuilder`, rather than accepting its parent interface (though this is not possible, as I've described above). Is there a cleaner, obvious alternative design pattern that I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you don't have any interfaces.  If you were to add a `IAppQueryBuilder` interface I think it would address your concern, and also make it much easier on your unit testers, who will be able to substitute a stub instead of mocking the concrete instance.